# divs still show up despite setting entire body to visibility:hidden - what's wrong?

Tags: css, printing

This is the configuration:

```
@media print {
  body {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  #printhtml {
    visibility: visible;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

And yet other divs on my page, apart from `printhtml`, are showing up when printing the entire page. I tried setting those divs to `display:none` and it worked. But the space they used to occupy (now blank) continues to exist and the print output always has 3 blank pages.

What am I missing here?

Btw, below is the other section of the page with the script and HTML codes. The divs `stubborn1`, `stubborn2`, and `stubborn3` are the ones continuing to show up. Again, they disappear when I set them to `display:none` but are replaced with blank spaces when printing, which shouldn't be the case.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.print();
}
</script>

<div style="width:78%; float:left;">
<div id="printhtml">
I want to print this page
</div>
&nbsp;
<hr>
<a title="View Page in PDF" href="/pdf-URL"><img src="/image1.png" /></a>&nbsp;<a href="" title="Print Page" onclick="myFunction()"><img src="/print.png" /></a>
</div>
<div id="stubborn1" style="width:20%; float:right;"><img src="/image2.jpg" style="position:fixed; margin-top:-70px; z-index:21;" />
</div>
<div id="stubborn2" ><img src="/image3.png" style="position:fixed; margin:215px 0px 0px 20px; z-index:21;" /></div>
<div id="stubborn3" ><img src="/image4.png" style="position:fixed; margin:215px 0px 0px 122px; z-index:21;" />
</div>
```

Comment: can you show us any more of your html/css?

when you use chrome developer tools and emulate 'print' does the space still remain?

Comment: Have you tried removing those 3 divs manually(from your HTML file) and try to print it? Just checking whether or not those 3 divs are your issue. Because as I know `display: hidden` will hide your element but still occupy its space, and `display:none` won't occupy its space.

Comment: @user3003216: I tried this and found out that the blank space is still there despite deleting the 3 divs. It's like as if the page has two body sections which just made it more confusing.

Comment: Well, try to remove all `&nbsp;` and `<hr>`, I guess those are the source of your issue. If not, then try put your `#printhtml` outside its parent div, and see what happen.

Comment: I did that but it didn't work. I still get 3 blank pages when printing when the 3 divs are set to `display:none`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't hide the entire body

Give the body contents in the div tags and give the class as 'hide'

and use this

```
@media print {
              .hide {
                display:none;
            }
      #printhtml {
        visibility: visible;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
      }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. If you mean renaming the classes of all other divs on the entire page (many of which I did not indicate above), that's not possible on my end. I have to think of other alts.

Comment: @SandyAAj which browser you are using?

Comment: I need to understand your requirement... You having a page with multiple contents and you need to hide some contents while printing , am i right ?

Comment: yeah. I want just `printhtml` to be printed and nothing more.

Comment: add the class="hide" in div, which you don't want to print. and use the style mentioned above in my comment. Its working fine for me in all browsers